# How does SMTP escape an RSET command after a DATA command?

Tags: email, smtp, rfc

In [RFC 821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821#page-25), it says that a reset (`RSET`) command can be sent after a `DATA` command and some mail data has been sent:

However, what distinguishes between a mail client sending an `RSET` command after `DATA`, and a mail that contains the word "RSET" on a line by itself?

I've checked [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) as well and I can't see anything that would mitigate or escape this.  It does talk about escaping a mail line which starts with a ".", but not "RSET".

The client cannot terminate the mail data transfer with a period on a line by itself or the server will send the partial mail it has been given.

I imagine there's something I've missed in the RFCs, otherwise I can't help thinking that there's either an SMTP command injection attack vector in many implementations, or no-one can ever send a mail with "RSET" on a line by itself (I think people would have noticed).

Answer (score 3):

The keyword here is *after* I believe.  The `DATA` command is in progress until it is finished with a lone `.` on a line.

Comment: Correct. Once you start a `DATA` command, you cannot abort it except to drop the connection.

Comment: Fair enough, except that the RFC states for `RSET` that "Any stored sender, recipients, and mail data must be discarded".  If `RSET` cannot be used between `DATA` and `.`, and the `.` will end the mail transaction and send the mail, in what situation would `RSET` ever have mail data to discard?

Comment: Probably this is why this passage was removed from 5321.  You'll notice that 5321 indirectly supersedes 821 (via 2821).

Comment: @tripleee – [RFC 5321 § 4.1.1.5 (RSET)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-4.1.1.5) states "any stored sender, recipients, and mail data MUST be discarded" so it at least survives there. See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53839085/519360).

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 5321 § 4.1.1.5 (RSET)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.1.5) states "any stored sender, recipients, and mail data MUST be discarded." This refers to the `MAIL FROM`, `RCPT TO`, and presumably `DATA` commands.

However, upon receiving the `.` following `DATA`, the message "MUST" be delivered (which may result in a failure but not a partial failure, see [§ 4.1.1.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.1.4)). This clears the buffer of everything `RSET` is supposed to do.

This means `RSET` merely elicits a `250 OK` response from the receiving server (a keep-alive, much like `NOOP`) and confirms to the sender that there is indeed no saved sender or recipient queued for the next message.

I do not know of a way to interrupt a `DATA` command to issue a `RSET`. The only way I know of to do that is to terminate the connection and establish a new one—and, just to be safe in the case of some odd resumption capability, I'd issue an `RSET` right after the `EHLO` or `HELO` (which the spec says is a `NOOP`). If there were such a way, it should be in RFC 5321 [§ 4.1.1.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.1.4), [§ 4.1.1.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.1.5), and/or [§ 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-3.3).